# Параллельные вычисления в Python

Tags: python, multiprocessing, распараллеливание

Пытаюсь написать код, который при получении новой строки через requests будет вызывать функцию get_value() отдельным процессом. Т.к. поток, получаемый через requests бывает довольно большой, и тогда обработка происходит с отставанием. Пытался реализовать разными способами, но в итоге не получается ничего вменяемого.
Вот что на данный момент есть:

```
from checkhash import get_value
from multiprocessing import Process
import subprocess
import requests
def get_hash():
    url = 'https://somesite'
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    for line in r.iter_lines():
        if line:
            hash = (str(line).split('"hash":"')[1].split('"')[0])
            print(hash)
            proc = Process(target=get_value(hash))
            procs.append(proc)
            proc.start()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    procs = []
    while True:
        get_hash()
```

насколько я понял, проблема в том, что срабатыват GIL, который ждёт, пока дочерний процесс завершится. Как это обойти?

Comment: Как Вы видите работу скрипта в идеале?

Comment: В идеале, чтобы при получении каждой новой строчки get_value() считалась отдельным процессом, не тормозя основную программу. То есть, условно, подалось из requests 20 строчек - открылось 20 процессов, которые будут считать каждый свой get_value()

Answer (score 2):

Вот пример простого скрипта, запускающего одновременно несколько процессов:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
import requests

urls = ["https://google.com",
        "https://ya.ru",
        "https://mail.ru",
        "https://bing.com",
        "https://yahoo.com",
        "https://duckduckgo.com"]

def handle(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    print(str(len(page.content)) + "\t" + url)

processes = []

for url in urls:
    p = Process(target = handle, args = (url, ))
    p.start()
    processes.append(p)

print("Processes started")

for p in processes:
    p.join()

print("Processes ended")
```

Работает вроде как нормально, но я всё же не уверен в корректности этого кода с точки зрения многопроцессности.

Ещё можно использовать [`multiprocessing.Pool`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.Pool), чтобы получить ограниченное количество потоков (при большом количестве процессов это имеет смысл, так как при превышении количества ядер увеличатся накладные расходы на переключение контекста и эффективность снизится).

Адаптируйте свой скрипт и получите желаемый результат.

Comment: В том-то и суть, что меня не особо волнует загрузка системы и race condition, для моей программы это совершенно не критично, в системе 24 ядра, нагрузку выдержит. Важно только быстродействие. Requests у меня выдаёт большой поток данных, и без параллельных вычислений я просто не успеваю их обработать. Спасибо за Ваш ответ, но Ваш код делает по сути примерно то же, что и мой текущий, я проверил, скорости недостаточно.

Comment: @DenisSamotuga, понял, сейчас поправлю. Обработка у Вас независимая, так ведь?

Comment: Да, независимая

Comment: @DenisSamotuga, обновил ответ. Кстати, присмотритесь к PyPy — на вычислительных задачах он нередко даёт прирост к производительности.

Comment: А так получается в общем-то то то же самое, что у меня, только с p.join(), который вроде как просто завершает процесс (где-то только что читал, что он и так завершается)

Comment: спасибо, обязательно ознакомлюсь

Comment: @DenisSamotuga, Вы правы - `join()` ожидает завершения процесса.

Answer (score 1):

Итак, в ходе моих изысканий была найдена связка asyncio + aiohttp. Получается наверное не совсем то, что я изначально спрашивал, но в итоге мою задачу решает так хорошо, что я после стольких бесплодных попыток аж кайфанул.

```
import requests
import aiohttp
import asyncio

async def get_hash():
    url = 'https://somesite'
    r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for line in r.iter_lines():
            if line:
                hash = (str(line).split('"hash":"')[1].split('"')[0])
                print(hash)
                #Далее идут преобразования, взятые из get_value(). Суть не в них, а в том, что они выполняются как и было надо, асинхронно

loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
asyncio.run(get_hash())
```